# No access to shared folder from html code ? how to fix it?

Tags: windows, networking

I windows and  in my network we have one folder for everyone with pics, pdf, etc. When i open browser and type address below.

**file://mysharedfolder/ourpics/mariobros.jpg**

i see this pictures without any prblems but when i do

```
<img src="file://mysharedfolder/ourpics/mariobros.jpg">
```

i have no access. So can i fix it or is permanent deny ? If i have access from browser why cant see pic from html code ? is not the same ?

It is like i have samba dir /home/my_pics/pics

```
guest ok = yes
force create mode = 775
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
path = /home/my_pics/pics
force directory mode = 775
```

But when i tried get access img src "/home/my_pics/pics/1.jpg" i have error 403
what can i do ? add some user?

Comment: You can't load images over `file://` domains. Try doing a local server where you can host your image(s) there.

Comment: @Edric: I think you can, but the problem is in cross-domain requests. I suspect it works _if and only if_ the HTML file is also hosted on `file://mysharedfolder/...`.